# Can log4j2 print only INFO level to a unique file?

Tags: log4j2

I have read all document,

```
if it accept   
    ThresholdFilter
```

rt, I read the document,  no such LevelMatchFilter

Comment: You mean, print INFO only but not the higher levels (such as WARN)? Not out of the box, no, you'd need to write your own code (probably an appender). Maybe you can get close enough by limiting to a specific logger? Or just filter out / ignore the higher levels at whatever consumes the log file.

Comment: Log4j2 has no suchLevelMatchFilter.... , log4j does have it....

Comment: Potential redundant question. Here is ans answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695133/log4j2-filter-particular-level-in-apender