# log4j2 - Threshold Filter seemingly not working on Console Appender

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am trying to setup my log4j2 (version 2.8.2) installation on a Spring web application but there's a catch, i'm still not able to sort out.
I am writing a console appender to let developers see **ERROR/FATAL logs in red**, and **INFO in black** but I see the error output two times (one in black and one in red).

This is my `log4j2.xml` file, I took also inspiration from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24697002/2260924), without luck:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
<Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n">
                <Filters>                       
                    <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT" />
                </Filters>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>

        <Console name="ErrorConsole" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n">
                <Filters>
                    <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
                </Filters>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

<Loggers>
<Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="ErrorConsole" level="error"/>
        </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

With this configuration when an exception happens it gets logged two times, one for each console appender.

Am i using the ThresholdFilter correctly?

From the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.0-beta7/manual/filters.html#ThresholdFilter) I read:

```
onMatch     String  Action to take when the filter matches. May be ACCEPT, DENY or NEUTRAL. The default value is NEUTRAL.
onMismatch  String  Action to take when the filter does not match. May be ACCEPT, DENY or NEUTRAL. The default value is DENY.
```

Comment: Ok, as it ALWAYS happens I found out what I was doing wrong 5 minutes after posting the question: it wasnt working because I was incorrectly formatting my xml; the <Filters> tag wasnt mean to be a child of the <PatternLayout> tag. Moving it outside makes it work.